# How do I sync my data in Postgresql to Algolia?

Tags: postgresql, algolia

I want to use Algolia but for somehow I dont find any docs about syncing the data from Postgresql to Algolia?

Scenario

1. User add an item to the Postgresql and immediately it syncs in the Algolia database

In node.js + mongodb there is a library called mongoolia.

Regards,

Comment: Did you find a solution?